# Need Ruby regexp for validating "A1:B2" string format

Tags: ruby, regex

I am in a search of a ruby regexp that will validate strings in the format: `"A1:B2"`. The letter in left part of the colon is between `A`-`F`, and right side of the colon is between `A`-`Z` not earlier in alphabetical order than the letter in the left side.

Some valid examples are `"A1:B2"`, `"A3:B4"`, `"A5:B6"`, `"C2:D3"`.

Some invalid examples are `"E1:A2"`, `"B4:A3"`.

In other words, consider an Excel table with six columns `A`-`F` and n rows, so `A1:B2` will cover the four cells `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2`.

Let me know if you find any regex matching with the above scenario.

Comment: If you are comparing it with Excel format, why does the relation between the numbers on both sides of the colon not matter while the relation between the letters matter?

Comment: In my case numbers do not matter as long as they are forming the upper left to lower right diagonal. So in this case numbers do not matter but the letters does

Comment: How can the numbers without any restrictions define an upper **left** to  lower **right** diagonal?

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure this cannot be done with regular expressions alone. You will probably have to use something like `/^([A-F])(\d):([A-Z])(\d)$/`, and then compare $1 to $3, and $2 to $4.

Example:

```
def validate(str)
    /^([A-F])(\d):([A-Z])(\d)$/.match(str) && $1 < $3 && $2 < $4 
end
```

(Assuming that you only want to allow one letter and one digit on each side of the colon.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single regex. You could however do it with sth like

```
def validate(str)
  a,b = str.split(":")
  !(/([A-F])\d/ =~ a).nil? && !(/[#{$1}-Z]\d/ =~ b).nil?
end
```

Explanation:

the first character will be put into $1 and then inserted into the second regex, this way you will always match from the character you had in the first part.

example:

```
1.9.2p290 :039 > validate("A1:B2")
 => true 
1.9.2p290 :040 > validate("B2:A1")
 => false
```